# C# Microsoft Visual Studio Release Mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I created a C# project using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode and then built it in release mode so that I could run the code on some other machine without Visual Studio. I was motivated by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057878/how-to-compile-the-finished-c-sharp-project-and-run-it-outside-visual-studio).

Everything seemed to work fine. However, my ' .../bin/release  '  folder has .dll files and not .exe which I could just copy and run from the other machine.

How could I work around this?

EDIT: Here's the solution explorer screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Is your project a DLL? Did you get any build errors?

Comment: What type of project? Did you change anything in the project properties by hand from defaults?

Comment: what type of project is it (you can see it in the project's properties window)?

Comment: What kind of Project is it? You should also check the "Active Solution Configuration" for Release builds - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx - it could be that your main project output isn't being built in a release build.

Comment: As the others have stated, we need a lot more information before we can help you. Maybe a screenshot of your solution explorer + what type of project it is?

Comment: Is the Output Path on the .exe project properties (if it is one), set to "\bin\Release"?

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov: No I did not change any properties manually.

Comment: That's an Excel file project.  It isn't going to have an EXE.

Comment: @SLaks: Then is there a way to run the project without having Visual studio?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Build, Publish within Visual Studio.

Comment: I did this and it created a setup file and a folder called 'Application files'...

Comment: The 'application files' folder contains .deploy files ...but How could I run the project using these?