# Discord.Net Bot on a Rasberry Pi 3

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-2017

I searched for a long time, but found no good tutorial or something simillar. Like the Titel says it‘s about c#. The thing is I do not know how to Export my Console App as a standalone program (Visual Studio 2017) Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You build it and then move the executable + all necessary dll files to the target machine. A search should have revealed that much easily

Comment: Just all those dll Files?

Comment: Yes, the build folder has the executable and the dll files it needs. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057878/how-to-compile-the-finished-c-sharp-project-and-then-run-outside-visual-studio

Comment: Okay Thanks so far :) will Test it out tomorrow.